# Can I validate to make sure that the posted data from a Symfony2 choice form field is within its choice list?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, select

I'm creating a Symfony2 form.

Can I validate to make sure that the posted data from a choice field is within its choice list?

Comment: Do you have code which is not working, or is this a general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the choice validation constraint.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html

Answer (score 1):

In choice field ,there is a property named `strict` set to `true`
By default its value is `false`